# Windows Docker Container > Layout of rendered PDF is different when application is running on docker

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-instances, windows-container

After I resolved [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779075/how-to-add-fonts-to-windows-docker-container-image/59781433), I am facing an issue where PDF report has different layout than the one which rendered from local.

Please find below snapshot where you will see difference:

[image]

Below is the commands inside Dockerfile:

```
# app image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019  AS BASE
COPY arial*.ttf c:/windows/fonts/
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT BackgroundService.exe
```

Comment: You might be using other fonts as well that you didn't copy. Your 2 pdf's have more differences. For example look at the space in the header after "Quantity" and "Total" (there is a lot more space in the docker version. Also your blured lines start more to the right in the docker version (which might indicate that the size of the spaces there is bigger). Also make sure that you really are running the same version of the software (the docker version has a final total that is missing in the non-docker version)

Comment: Hello Mihai, 

Thanks for your reply. I am using the same version of software - one with docker and another without docker. I just ran application locally and generated PDF and with the same application(code), I generated docker image and deployed.

For Fonts, I have copied all fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts to docker image but still the same problem. I think I must need to copy some other files/DLL which is being used by .NET framework while generating PDFs and which is available on my local machine but not on docker container.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you end up getting this resolved?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapati Is this issue get resolved?